# Exclude records after the first change in a field value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

```
AnswerBaseID    EpisodeSetID    EpisodeNumber   ProposedTreatmentID_OD
107                 95          1               2
108                 95          2               3
109                 96          1               2
110                 96          2               3
111                 96          3               2
120                 103         1               2
121                 103         2               2
```

EpisodeSets have a variable number of episodes: EpisodeSet 95 has 2 episodes associates, EpisodeSet 96 has 3 episodes associates and EpisodeSet 103 has two episodes associates. all episodeSets start with a proposed treatment 2 that might change in subsequent episodes.
For example in EpisodeSet 96 the episodes set changes from 2 to 3 in the second episodes number. I would like to exclude all the record after the first change from 2 until different number occurs.

So in the EpisodeSet 96, I would like to exclude episode number 2 and 3 even if episode number 3 is again a proposed treatment two. In the end, I would like my results to look like:

```
AnswerBaseID    EpisodeSetID    EpisodeNumber   ProposedTreatmentID_OD
107                 95          1               2

109                 96          1               2

120                 103         1               2
121                 103         2               2
```

How can I write such a query?

Comment: Two questions:  1) what database engine are you writing the query for? 2) what have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to keep the first record for each `EpisodeSetId` based on the `EpisodeNumber`.

Here is one method that works across all databases:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.EpisodeSetId = t.EpisodeSetId and
                        t2.EpisodeNumber < t.EpisodeNumber
                 );
```

Comment: Not quite Gordon, for example in EpisodeSet 103 I keep all records as there is not transition of proposedTreatmentID_OD from 2 to another no. Thank you for the attempt, I will try to use the suggestion adn modify it to obtain what I am looking for

Comment: @user1536396 . . . What database are you using?

Comment: @user1536396 . . . Then what you want to do is basically impossible without going through the records one row at a time using VBA.  I would suggest you switch to a more powerful database, such as SQL Server Express (which is free).